# Need Auth0 rememberLastLogin parameter info for plain link option

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, oauth-2.0, auth0

I am using Auth0 and I have integrated it with Plain link so Auth0 Lock UI is rendering from that link so for this I have to set `rememberLastLogin` to false.

Anyone Having an idea how to pass this parameter with link.

Thanks,
Mit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are redirecting to Auth0 for authentication (i.e. not showing an embedded Lock on your website), you can customize the Auth0-hosted Lock through the dashboard, in the "Login Page" section: https://manage.auth0.com/#/login_page

Comment: Is this possible to Integrate reset password functionality into our own html form with this redirecting to Auth0?